# lsb3.2 Epson printer error in Xenial

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

With Ubuntu 15.10 my Epson L355 printer installed without any troubles. Now, with Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) the printer's installation failed.

Before Xenial, I added to the sources list:

```
deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main
```

And after that, installed the driver:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201207w
```

But now, I get an error:

```
Depends: lsb (>=3.2) but it is not installable
```

I tried:

- to download and install the driver from the [Epson's web page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)
- to download and install lsb-core and lsb-security from the [Debian's web page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lsb-core)

But, the error persists...

Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/763157/ubuntu-16-04-installing-epson-driver-fails-on-lsb-3-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lsb` package no longer exists in Xenial, so this package cannot normally be installed on it. You should wait for Epson to release a Xenial-compatible package, but in the meantime it should be fine to install [the `lsb-` packages from Wily](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/lsb), since those packages do not install anything themselves (they only depend on other packages).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need solve LSB problem... **install driver directly** and then add printer (automaticaly).

See https://askubuntu.com/a/763268/238367

Answer (score 2):

After a few failures and getting the lsb3.2 error I installed the driver at the top of the list at:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult
It reads.

```
WF-7520 Series
    Printer Driver  Linux
    latest  ESC/P Driver (full feature)     All language
    02-07-2012
```

It installed without errors and gave me a whole lot of features, not available previously, like economy and draft mode printing. It prints from cassette 1 only at this stage, so a bit more fiddling yet to come. The new features are great and I'm happy to just swap paper trays for different size paper at this time.

I'm no expert (yet) so any further help I can give will be limited. I installed the 64-bit deb file using Gdebi. I believe this suitable for a host of other epson printers.

```
Package to download is epson-inkjet-printer-201115w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```